Can't find datasheet for Bluetooth IC BP 1P348-6684
I want to connect a mic to my Bluetooth module (BP 1P348-6684). But I can't find datasheet for this module.

Ic no - BP 1P348-6684

You need to ask a question.

And put all the information in the question, not buried in the comments. I suggest you change your question title to "Can't find datasheet for Bluetooth IC BP 1P348-6684" so that someone who recognises the part number may be enticed to answer your "question".

Indentifying a JL chip in a Bluetooth has a link to the Zuhai Jie Li (珠海杰理) manufacturers website, which might help you to find a datasheet. Can you [edit] the question to include a picture of the other side of the module? Can't find the datasheet of cheap Bluetooth audio receiver has some information about the pinout of a similar looking module, albeit a different IC part number, whereby the silk screen on the other side gives a clue about the connections.

Even if you were to find a datasheet, how do you know that the hardware (and potentially firmware) is built to accept audio input?
